# C# - How to Decrypt an Encrypted Private Key with Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, encryption, bouncycastle

I have a private key that was generated by running:

```
openssl req -new -sha384 -x509 -days 63524 -subj "/C=CA/ST=State/L=City/O=Org/CN=Org-CA" -extensions v3_ca -keyout Org-CA.key -out Org-CA.pem -passout pass:pass1234
```

I need to use this private key and certificate to sign client CSRs.  I used to use OpenSSL to do this, but I need to do this in C# instead.

I've found examples of what I want to do online, but those examples are using bouncy castle and an un-encrypted private key.

The key file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I'm trying to load it by doing this:

```
var privatekey = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Org-CA.key");
var rsaKeyParameters = PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey("pass1234".ToArray(), privatekey);
```

But thats not working.  I get an error saying `Wrong number of elements in sequence (Parameter 'seq')'`

Is this how I'm supposed to be decrypting and loading the private key?

Comment: You use something like `new X509Certificate2(fileName, pw)`, `GetECDsaPrivateKey()` or `Export()` to extract the keys from the certificate. Also take a look at `RSA.Create(4096)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the normal methods expect a DER encoded structure. Such a structure usually consists of at least one SEQUENCE, hence the error. You first need to parse the PEM or find  a utility function that handles PEM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your .NET version, you may not need BouncyCastle at all. As of .NET Core 3.1 there is [`RSA.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importencryptedpkcs8privatekey?view=net-6.0) for DER encoded encrypted private PKCS#8 keys and as of .NET 5.0 there is even [`RSA.ImportFromEncryptedPem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfromencryptedpem?view=net-6.0) for PEM encoded encrypted keys.

---

Otherwise with C#/BouncyCastle the import of an encrypted private PKCS#8 key is available e.g. with:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
...
string encPkcs8 = @"-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
                    ...
                    -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"; 
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(encPkcs8);
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(stringReader, new PasswordFinder("<your password>"));
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters keyParams = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();
...
```

with the following implementation of the `IPasswordFinder` interface:

```cs
private class PasswordFinder : IPasswordFinder
{
    private string password;
    public PasswordFinder(string pwd) => password = pwd;
    public char[] GetPassword() => password.ToCharArray();
}
```

If necessary, a conversion from `keyParams` to `System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters` is possible with:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
...
RSAParameters rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyParams);
```

which can be imported directly e.g. with [`RSA.ImportParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importparameters?view=net-6.0).

---

**Edit:**
After digging through the C#/BouncyCastle source code, your way is also possible (which I didn't know before).
`DecryptKey()` has several overloads, one of which can handle the DER encoded encrypted key as already suspected by Maarten Bodewes in his comment. The latter can be easily generated with the `Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader()` class.
Note that this `PemReader` is different from the one in the first implementation (different namespaces), which is why I use the namespace explicitly in the following code snippet. With this approach, the `RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters` instance can be generated as follows:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
...
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(encPkcs8);
Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader(stringReader);
Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemObject pem = pemReader.ReadPemObject();
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters keyParams = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.DecryptKey("<your password>".ToCharArray(), pem.Content);
...
```

`pem.Content` contains the DER encoded encrypted private PKCS#8 key.